# SSL Certificate seen as invalid by older versions of IE

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl

I'm encountering a problem with a SSL certificate.
Everything works perfect in Opera, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE9, and the Certificate is perceived as being valid (just as it should be).
However, IE8, 7 and below won't open the page

Do you have any idea what might be wrong with the certificate?

You can see the secure version here: https://secure-load.com (the page is blank)

Thank you for your help

**Edit**

In case anyone else has this problem, it was the SNI in our case. Once we took care of that, everything went just fine

Comment: How did you fix SNI? I thought it was a client-side issue?

Comment: I honestly can't remember... I was not the only one working on this problem, there was also a back-end guy who did most of the tinkering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The certificate you are using was issued by StartCom. 
According to [this forum post](https://forum.startcom.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1460) the StartCom CA was added as trusted root CA by Microsoft in 2009. 
May be the clients that do not accept the certificate are running on system which are older and that did not install the trusted certificate updates. You can check that by opening the `certmgr.msc` management console.

For Windows XP you can download the most recent trusted root CA list here:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6149

Afterwards any IE running on the updated system should accept the certificate.

**Update**: Alternatively there may a different reason:
The server you are using is hosting multiple HTTPS sites with different certificates. This requires a feature called "[Server Name Indication (SNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)" on client side. 
According to Wikipedia on Windows XP IE7 and 8 do not support SNI and therefore get back the wrong certificate from the server (in this case the one from www.snakeoil.dom).

Comment: Thank you, your answer was really helpful! Now it's down to pinpointing the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

You can check the reason why the older IE version are not able to validate the certficate. What @Robert has said could exactly be the reason. You can download and add the StartCom CA certificate to your truststore on older IE versions. That should probabaly fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not me I'm worried about, is the others who visit the site